# How to get "this" form content by name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following example I get `title` from `this` form using html `id=title`.

How do I do the same, but instead of using ID then using name?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form').live('submit', function(){

    var aform = $('form[name="create_form"]');

    // get the entire form
    var form = $(this);

    // get form title field by ID
    var title = this.elements.title.value;

    // get selected radio button using name instead if ID
    var type = $(this).find('input:radio[name="ctype"]:checked').val() || '';

    alert(title);
```

In the case of the radio button, is it gotten by name, but I can't figure out how to translate that syntax to a normal form field of

```
<input name="title" id="55544_title" type="text" />
```

Comment: it is the same syntax, JS works on the DOM regardless of which kind of element is selected, can you provide the full HTML / form code?

Comment: can't you use: `var title = $('input[name=title]',form).val();`

Comment: Your question seems a little confused. Are you wanting to get the value of "name" for each form element, just one, or the form itself?

Comment: Hmmm, if i understand You right `$('form[name="create_form"] input[name="title"]').val();` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line

```
// get form title field by ID
var title = this.elements.title.value
```

you are not getting it with the id, you are getting it with the name attribute, so in some way you are already doing it correctly

Comment: A radio button only makes sense if there is more than one. The above will return a collection (NodeList) of radio buttons with the same name, attempting to get its value property will return "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just do:

```
var title = $('input[name=title]',form).val();
```

instead of:

```
var title = this.elements.title.value
```

Comment: When I do that I get `form is not defined`.

Comment: what, your defining `form` above: `var form = $(this);`

Comment: Ups. Sorry. I had commented it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find(":input[name='title']");
```

should work

Comment: When I do that `alert()` prints `[object Object]` and not the value I entered in the form field

Comment: I forgot to add the method '.val()'. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
>     // get form title field by ID
>     var title = this.elements.title.value;
```

Within the listener, `this` is the form (since the listener is attached to the form). If there is more than one element with a name of 'title' then:

```
this.elements.title
```

will be a collection. It is that object that you are trying to access the *value* property of. If you want a reference to the radio button within the collection that is checked, then:

```
$(this).find('input:radio[name="ctype"]:checked')
```

will return a jQuery object with your input as its only element, so:

```
var checkedButton = $(this).find('input:radio[name="ctype"]:checked')[0];
```

should do the trick (if one is selected). Or you can iterate over the elements returned by `this.elements.title` to find the selected one:

```
var checkedButton, buttons = this.elements.title;

if (buttons.tagName) {
  checkedButton = buttons;

} else {

  for (var i=0, iLen=buttons.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if (buttons[i].checked) {
      checkedButton = buttons[i];
    }
  }
}
```